# Nested template parameters and type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

Hi I am practicing with templates and type deduction and wanted to try making a simple function template with nested template parameters to print out the contents of any stl container:

```
template <template<T, ALLOC> CONT> 
void Print(const CONT<T, ALLOC> &c) {

    for (const T &elem : c) std::cout << elem << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

And my test case:

```
int main() {
    std::list<int> intlist{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::vector<float> floatvec{ 0.2f, 0.5f };

    Print(intlist);
    Print(floatvec);
}
```

However I am getting a compiler error whereby the types for T and ALLOC cannot be deduced. Is there a way for me to write this function without having to explicit state the types for the template arguments?

Note that my object here is to be able to deduce the type stored within the passed in stl container. Hence if a vector of ints was passed in T would be deduced to type Int.

Comment: The template itself shouldn't even compile.. `template<T, ALLOC> CONT` says that `CONT` is a template with two non-type template parameters whose types are `T` and `ALLOC`. This should cause name lookup of `T` and `ALLOC` which should fail. -- Like this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50c8edf643ed26f0

Comment: Oh, *and* you forgot the `class` before `CONT`, if this is supposed to be a template *template-parameter*: `template<template</*something*/> class CONT>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you may simply do

```
template <typename CONT> 
void Print(const CONT& c) {
    for (const auto& elem : c) std::cout << elem << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

If you want to restrict your `Print` function to template classes with 2 template arguments, the syntax would be:

```
template <template<typename , typename> class CONT, typename T, typename ALLOC> 
void Print(const CONT<T, ALLOC> &c) {
    for (const T &elem : c) std::cout << elem << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the first one is what I had in the first place but I need to deduce the type stored within the CONT parameter. Hence the nested templated version.

That seems rather confusing, having 3 template parameters for the outermost template parameters and 2 anonymous template parameters for the class CONT.

Could you explain how I would call the print function explicitly with the passed in template arguments? I need to understand this thoroughly especially the type deduction part.

Comment: @ChristopherLeong: stl containers define some type to retrieve their template parameter as `std::vector<..>::value_type`.

Comment: You may call `Print` explicitly with `Print<std::vector, float, std::allocator<float>>(floatvec);`